# JavaScript regex where no two symbols go one after another and at least one such symbol is present

Tags: javascript, regex, string, validation, text

How could I write a JavaScript regex where no two symbols go one after another and at least one such symbol is present?

In my case I am writing an email validation. And I have the following regex for a domain part right now:

```
/^([.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\-\w\d]){1,253}$/
```

Now I want to add the following conditions:

**1** The domain should always contain at least one dot

**2** The dot can not be the first or the last character in a string

**3** There can be no two consecutive dots

How can I do this? Thank you.

For example, the string `foo.foo.foo` will be fine. While the strings `foo`, `.foo`, `foo..foo` are not fine for my example.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input/output to clarify what it is you are looking for?

Comment: do you need to check for particular symbol in the email?

Comment: @AlexanderNied, just updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi, just updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: `^(?=.{1,253}$)[!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~\w-]+(?:\.[!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~\w-]+)+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var arr = [
 'foo.foo.foo',
 'f.foo',
 'foo..foo',
 '.foo',
 'foo.',
  'foo'
];

arr.forEach(a => {
 console.log(a, /^\w+(\.\w+)+$/g.test(a) && a.length <= 253 )
});
```

hope that helps you

Comment: It does not restrict the length of the string. Thank for an attempt to help anyway (y).

Comment: but it fulfills all your criterias, what about the length?

Comment: even though the length can be checked with a regex, if it's the overall string length what you care about, I'd rather use the JS property to check the length as it's easier to read and more performance efficient

Comment: Hm. Thank you. That solves my issue a lot. Just one more question. So, in your regex you are ensuring that the strings starts with a character symbol, then you make sure that there is a dot and at least one more character and you just repeat the pattern. Am I right?

Comment: And why do you add a `g` at the end? I know from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) that it is a global search flag, but I can not understand how does it help us in this case, since we are already testing the whole string. Could you, please, provide and example when the regex won`t work correctly if we remove the `g`?

Comment: it means "global" but here it's not needed, it's needed in text files where multiple lines are present, but I put it everywhere as it caused a lot of issues in the past when not using it :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/^(?!\.\.)\w*(\.?\w+)*$/
```

works correct for `foo`, `.foo` and `foo..foo`

Comment: It does not restrict the length of the string. Thank for an attempt to help anyway (y).